# Cannot call Phone gap api

Tags: javascript, cordova

Im unable to call "navigator.globalization.getLocaleName" from the Phone Gap API.
    What am I doing wrong?

I have added all the APIs correctly

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function checkLocale() {
  navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
    function (locale) {alert('locale: ' + locale.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting locale\n');}
  );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the three executive statements directly into function onDeviceReady().

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function onDeviceReady() 
        {

              navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
            function (locale) {alert('locale: ' + locale.value + '\n');},
            function () {alert('Error getting locale\n');}
                    );
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error ,, cause i am getting alert locale: en_US from the above ! Which version of cordova are you using ?

Comment: Solved. Thank you. There was issue with the installation.